# Sailjs code to retrieve list of author for forum ineffecient

Tags: javascript, node.js, nested, sails.js

I am writing a discussion board using SailsJs and I have a `topic` in which there is a question and a bunch of replies. Now the replies are by various users and the `replyObject` contains just the `authorId`. I also need to show the `authorName` for each reply. Using my limited understanding I have written the following controller:

```
'showTopic': function(req, res, next) {
if(req.param('id')!=null) {
    Topic.findOne(req.param('id'), function foundTopic(err, topic) {
        Reply.find({
          topicId: topic.id
        }).done(function(err, replies) {
          if (err) return next(err);
          if (!replies) return next();         

          var authorIds = [];
          var authorList = [];

          for(var reply =0; reply<replies.length; reply++) {
            var authorId = replies[reply].authorId;
            if(authorIds.indexOf(authorId) === -1) {
              authorIds.push(authorId);
              User.findOne(authorId , function foundUser(err, author) { 
               if (err) return next(err);
               authorList.push(author);               
             });
            }
          };

          res.view({
            topic: topic,
            replies: replies,
            authors: authorList
          });
     });
}
```

This code also is beginning to look like a deeply nested function but I am not exactly sure how to use [eventproxy](https://github.com/JacksonTian/eventproxy/blob/master/README_en.md) to make it cleaner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've never used EventProxy, but after giving it a quick look I don't think it's what you need here, as it is concerned with (unsurprisingly) *events*, where you are looking to simplify nested asynchronous callbacks that aren't event based.  I'd recommend using the [async library](https://github.com/caolan/async) instead, which would let you rewrite the above as:

```
'showTopic': function(req, res) {

  if (req.param('id') == null) {
      return res.send("No topic ID sent!");
  }

  var authorList = [];
  async.auto({

     // Find the topic, and send it as an argument to the callback
     topic: function(cb) {Topic.findOne(req.param('id')).exec(cb);},

     // Find the replies, in parallel to the above
     replies: function(cb) {Reply.find({topic: req.param('id')}).exec(cb);},

     // After "replies" is done, construct the author list
     authors: ['replies', function(cb, results) {

        // async.auto stores the results of everything that ran before
        var replies = results.replies;

        // Get the unique list of authors using Lodash (you could write
        // this manually if you don't want to include the Lodash library!)
        var authorIds = _.unique(_.pluck(replies, 'authorId'));

        // Find all the authors with those IDs
        User.find({id: authorIds}).exec(cb);

     }]

  },

     // The second argument to async.auto is called when all of the
     // tasks complete, or if any of the callbacks returns an error
     function finished (err, results) {

        if (err) {return res.serverError(err);}
        res.view({
          topic: results.topic,
          replies: results.replies,
          authors: results.authors
        });

     } 

  );

}
```

See the [docs for async.auto](https://github.com/caolan/async#auto) for more info.

**Notes**: You'll need to `npm install` and `require` the async and Lodash libraries for the above to work (although you could rewrite it to not use Lodash if you wanted to).  Also, you should almost never need to use (or even declare) `next` in your Sails controller.  Controllers should be the last stop in the middleware chain except in rare circumstances, and if you find yourself wanting to use `next`, you can probably solve your problem with [policies](https://github.com/balderdashy/sails-docs/blob/master/policies.md) instead.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I am just getting started of with node so there are some good practices I suppose I need to pick up on. I will give this method a go and check if this suits my purpose.